# Is it possible to apply CSS transitions inline?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to apply CSS transitions inline (in the DOM), without using Pseudo Selector or using JS to add and change a property `class` on the dom?
.

```css
#target{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="target" style="transition: opacity 1s linear;"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, we can. However, just because you can doesn't mean you should ;-)

Comment: @JohnSlegers why not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Transitions need a changing value to produce any effect. This is usually achieved, as you mentioned, by toggling a class or using a pseudo selector.

If you want your "transition" to happen without any changing values, you need to use an animation:

```css
#target{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}

@keyframes fadeMe {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="target" style="animation: fadeMe 2s;"></div>
```

I'm not sure why you would need to do this inline though.

Comment: A great reason to do this is for cut and paste HTML (for example, to provide an inline advertisement).

Comment: A reason for needing to do this inline is because you're writing this using a wiki that doesn't allow any other method.

Comment: Another reason is when working with dynamic values from javascript like width for example.

Answer (score 5):

Combining with inline javascript you can achieve that, try this one:

```css
#target{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;  
}
```

```html
<div id="target" style="transition: all 4s linear;" onclick="this.style.opacity = '.3'">click me</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work with just about any kind of DOM update, not limited to inline javascript. I've just verified transitions working in Chrome using ReactJS to update inline styles in the render() method. I don't know if there are limitations.